# Filter Left Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to properly filter data in left join?

My task is to create a view of the current load of support units by calculating the number of requests assigned to each one of the support units:

There are two tables in my MS SQL database :

- `Contact`, which contains Support Units
- `Case`, which contains requests

If I do a simple left join, the output data is OK:

```
Select Contact.Id, count([Case].OwnerId) as [Count] from Contact 
left join [Case] on Contact.Id = [Case].OwnerId
Group By Contact.Id;
```

Output:

| Contact | Count |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 0 |
| Id2 | 2 |
| id3 | 0 |
| Id4 | 1 |

The problem here is that I only need cases that have a certain status:

```
Select Contact.Id, count([Case].OwnerId) as [Count] from Contact 
left join [Case] on Contact.Id = [Case].OwnerId
Where [Case].StatusId = 'some id here'
```

I receive this:

| Contact | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Id2 | 2 |
| Id4 | 1 |

The records that have 0 in column Count disappear from the result.

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Can you share your two input tables and your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it to the join statement:

```
Select Contact.Id, count([Case].OwnerId) as [Count] from Contact 
left join [Case] on Contact.Id = [Case].OwnerId 
and [Case].StatusId = 'some id here'
Group By Contact.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output both (with count >0 and count==0). You can add or condition like:

```
Select Contact.Id, count([Case].OwnerId) as [Count] from Contact
 left join [Case] on Contact.Id = [Case].OwnerId
 Where ([Case].StatusId = 'some id here' or [Case].id is null);
```

Comment: Thanks, it totally worked as expected!

Comment: @YuriiSokil always happy to help